# "At another date" vs. "on another date"

Tags: prepositions

Can you please tell me if both *at another date* and *on another date* are perfectly natural in the context below?

> I'm afraid I work on November 25th, but we can meet up **at another date**.
>
> I'm afraid I work on November 25th, but we can meet up **on another date**.

Answer (score 1):

"On another date" is more natural when talking about a meeting at some point during the day. It conveys that the meeting happens over some unspecified period within the day.

"At another date" is more natural for something like a deadline or a change in state (e.g. "The website will go live at another date"). It conveys that the event is a single, instantaneous event.

Answer (score 0):

"On" sounds more natural to me here, though "at" doesn't sound terrible. My gut feeling is that "at" is more often used with "date" for very vague things, like: "We intend the project to be resumed at a later date."

For what it's worth, I think "another day" is better in this case, without any preposition at all.

I also recommend replacing "I work" on November 25th with "I'm working" or "I'll be working" on November 25th. The simple present can also sometimes be used to indicate future plans - so "I work" isn't necessarily wrong - but I'd call it kind of an advanced stylistic maneuver and it won't come across well until everything else is perfect.

So my alternative, more natural-sounding version, is:

> I'm afraid I'll be working on November 25th, but we can meet up another day.

Comment: What? This is utterly wrong. There are rules for prepositions of time. Why make stuff up?

Comment: @Astralbee, I know that I you're angry that I disagreed with you elsewhere, but this is truly immature.

Comment: That's not the case. I couldn't believe how far you were willing to argue an incorrect point so I thought I best investigate the quality of your other answers as I care very much about this site and have put a lot of time and energy into it. Frankly, I'm horrified, and will continue to observe closely.

Comment: How far *I'm* willing to go? My dear @Astralbee, you've gone as far as to go to another answer of mine (this one), downvote it, call it "utterly wrong", and post your own answer which is consistent with my own! I think you're just a bit too sensitive about missing the nuance that I pointed out to you in our other discussion.

Comment: the difference between my answer and yours is that mine is factual and yours is opinion-based. I have stated that this is a rule of English and only one can be correct, while you have stated what sounds 'most natural' to you. I've linked to resources backing up my answer while you've referred to your 'gut feeling'. If your gut got the right answer by chance that doesn't help the OP learn how to get it right in future.

Comment: The OP specifically asked for what is natural. Read the question.

Comment: what is *correct* trumps what is 'natural'. If something goes against a rule of grammar it isn't just 'unnatural sounding' - it's wrong! Read the room.

Answer (score 0):

There are simple rules concerning prepositions with units of time. For example, something happens **on** a date, and **at** a time.

> Example:
>
> - It happened **on** the 1st of May.
> - It happened **at** 11am.

If any preposition is to be used in your example, it should be 'on':

> We can meet up on another day.

Alternatively, you can drop the preposition entirely in this particular instance:

> We can meet up another day.

There are some exceptions made when referring to a date *and* a time, for example:

> We can meet *at another date and time* convenient to you.

You can find some useful resources on prepositions of time [here](https://learnenglishkids.britishcouncil.org/grammar-practice/prepositions-time) and [here](https://learnenglishteens.britishcouncil.org/grammar/a1-a2-grammar/prepositions-of-time).